# OpenWhisk authentication issue (get username and password)

Tags: devops, serverless, openwhisk, faas

In OpenWhisk, I want to display the functions I deployed from wsk(cli) OpenWhisk's interface, for this I go to the site on the api host, but it asks for authentication information. Where to get authentication information in Openwhisk? As an alternative, what I've tried hasn't worked. When I type wsk property get it says whisk aut.

`wsk property set --apihost 'http://172.17.0.1:3233' --auth '23bc46b1-71f6-4ed5-8c54-816aa4f8c502:123zO3xZCLrMN6v2BKK1dXYFpXlPkccOFqm12CdAsMgRU4VrNZ9lyGVCGuMDGIwP'`

I could not enter the information written here when I typed the username and password.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2FRa.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this solution: If the --web true flag is used, you can also run functions from the web interface.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SZZrj.png)